Firebase Storage Images not loading in Flutter Web - CORS Error in Chrome and Safari
I'm building a Flutter web app that loads images from Firebase Storage. The app works fine on mobile but images fail to load on web browsers with CORS errors:

Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The image
element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Ftappglobal-app%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&gsessionid=(...)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

I've implemented CachedNetworkImage with proper headers:
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: imageUrl,
  httpHeaders: const {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
  },
  // Other config...
)

And deployed CORS settings:
[{
  "origin": ["*"],
  "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"], 
  "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
  "responseHeader": [
    "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "Cache-Control"
  ]
}]

I verified the Firebase Storage rules to ensure public read and authenticated write access are configured properly:
match /profiles/{userId}/{profileId}/{allImages=**} {
    allow read;  // Public access for profile images
    allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}

What I Tried:

Configured Firebase Storage rules for public read access
Deployed CORS configuration using gsutil cors set
Added CORS headers in CachedNetworkImage and Image.network
Tried different image loading approaches (Image.network, CachedNetworkImage)
Verified storage bucket name and configuration

Expected: Images should load properly in web browsers
Actual: Getting CORS errors in Chrome and Safari

The error message you quoted is for Firestore, which is a different product than Cloud Storage.  If you're having problems with Cloud Storage, then you might want to look for a different error that indicates the problem.  You might also want to edit the question be clear about how you're loading data from Cloud Storage.  Are you using a URL or Dart API?  How did you get it?  What is the problem with that URL specifically?
